# Dynamic encrypted paypal button?

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, paypal, payment

so I am creating a website that needs to have a subscribe PayPal button. I am currently using the [paypal button js](https://github.com/paypal/JavaScriptButtons), but it is very insecure, and people can change the amount they pay. So I am going to need to use the encrypted button, but I am not sure how to achieve this and still be able to change the price depending on the user. The reason I need to do this is so the user will be able to select different amounts of something. Say they can select anywhere from 1 to 50 points that would alter the price so if 1 point is 1 dollar and the user select 24 the subscribe button amount will have to be 24 dollars a month. Below is the current code for creating a non encrypted button. As a side question if anyone happens to know if it is important to keep your merchant id a secret. If so how would I do this?

```html
 $("#paypal-button").html(
  '<script src="js/paypal-button.min.js?merchant=[Merchant ID]"' +
   'data-button="subscribe"' +
   'data-name="Custom Howloop Subscription"' +
   'data-amount="' + roundTotal + '"' +
   'data-recurrence="1"' +
   'data-period="M"' +
   'async' +
  '> </script>'
 );
```

Comment: you should check the amount paid at the other end, its the only reliable way to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A long time ago I tried to do something similar to this.

To my knowledge, there is no way to do it. You won't be able to simply change the values of the encrypted button and if it isn't encrypted, the user can change it and basically pay anything.

If you want to be able to safely and dynamically change values, I would suggest looking into their API/Express Checkout. That's what I did, and I am really glad that I did.

You can check everything before it is forwarded to PayPal, and I have never had an issue with that aspect of it (I pass the item ID  and query my database to get the cost/etc and apply other checks to stop various issues.). And you can go through and apply any calculations that you need to for the price without an issue.

Otherwise, the only way I could think of is having multiple encrypted buttons for different prices. But that isn't very fun nor an optimal solution.

Edit: Now that I am not on mobile, here is a link to the [Express Checkout Getting Started Guide.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/)

Also, I do not believe that you need to worry about your Merchant ID being seen. It is used to process payments and I believe it can be seen in the transaction details.

Comment: You know I took a look at the API/Express Checkout a while ago and maybe I was doing it incorrectly (Which is pretty likely) but anyway I was using ajax to POST the sandbox endpoint and I was getting a error because it was on a different domain. Is this the correct way of doing it?

Comment: I am going to be honest, I am not entirely sure of how you were trying to do it. But I can give you a brief idea of the flow/process. You declare the api credentials, return url, cancel url, paypal mode (live/sandbox) and some other things. Data is passed through to your processing script, which is where you will set the variables for prices, etc (Basically where you would query your database to get the correct data). The data/user is directed to PayPal to make the payment. Once completed, they are redirected back to the declared return URL where you store the data/display a completed page.

Comment: There is more that plays into it (tokens, requests, etc) than what I stated, but at least it gives you very basic idea of how the flow works. Also, you may notice that there is an IPN and ExpressCheckout. They are different, and you could use both, or one or the other. For example, an echeck would be marked as pending by ExpressCheckout as it is pending at the time of processing. The IPN would be notified once payments are updated/changed and you could updated the database accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

YES THERE IS A WAY! Dont listen to the nay-sayers, i have recently successfully implemented encryption on dynamically created shopping cart information which was being injected into a empty form using php. I'm really planning to create a full tutorial because it seems that this information is RARE (i wonder why Paypal doesn't have a standard tutorial for this). I remember having days of stress because of this problem and almost a month later i happened to stumble on a tutorial provided here: https://www.stellarwebsolutions.com/en/articles/paypal_button_encryption_php.php

After some minor modifications i was able to use the PHP code to encrypt the data using my generated private keys and public certificates (make sure u have HTTPS on your website). Paypal was then able to successfully decrypt the information! (Oh boy you bet i did the happy dance)

Making sure data is valid only using IPN after payment is made is a very messy approach when u can avoid most tampering by doing custom encryption. Anyways until i buckle down and create a video tutorial good luck with the endeavor - on looking back i see how truly simple this process really is!

Comment: I would be careful, the article is dated 2010.

Comment: it seems to be alright, and also encryption is always better than none in this case

Comment: Thank you for your response and the link I will be taking a look at them and giving a attempt to implement it make sure you post a link to your video when you make it I would love to see it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this without hosting the button details on PayPal's side. This would also happen in an old-style PayPal form integration where anyone can go into Chrome's Devtools and alter html form variables for example. As a workaround, you can implement one hosted subscribe button and have users change the quantity of the subscription. If your prices scale linearly with quantity of points then it'll work.